# When we add two realizations of random variables Y_i (eg. sample mean), are the omegas or the random variables (functions) being indexed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Without an explicit definition of $\Omega$, how do I interpret the example below?

Example: let $$-7 = (\bar{y}) = \frac{Y_1 + Y_2}{2} = \frac{10+4}{2}$$

Are we indexing $Y_1(\omega)$ or $Y(\omega_1)$?

What's the convention here?

Comment: The convention is $Y_1(\omega) + Y_2(\omega)$. The interpretation is that there is only one observed outcome: namely, $\omega$. The random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are determined by the details of that outcome.

Comment: @DavidKraemer In the context of a coin-flip experiment where $Y_1 = 0$ and $Y_2 = 1$, what would $\omega$ be then? $\omega=$(Tail,Heads)? How about a sample of students with random variable $H_i$ being each individual $i$'s height?